# String Ranking Algorithm in mySQL like Quicksilver

Tags: mysql, search, autocomplete, fuzzy-search

## String Ranking Algorithm in mySQL

**Quicksilver Scoring Algorithms**

[PHP Port](https://gist.github.com/383465)
[Javascript Port](https://github.com/joshaven/string_score/blob/master/string_score.js)
MySql Port (oh No link) that's my issue Keep Reading

**Example Usage:**

```
score("hello world","axl") //=> 0.0  
score("hello world","ow") //=> 0.6  
score("hello world","hello world") //=> 1.0
```

Ok so my question lies here. As awesome as these are, And thank you to those who make it possible! I would love for a mysql way of doing this. Database aren't my area of expertise but **if I wanted to do this in just MySQL, how would i do it?** AND **Should I, is there a better way?**.

My thinking on this is as such.

***Real Life Example:***

I have 14000+ records in my database. A table of "*ICD9*" Medical Codes which has a medical code and a description.

Table:
**ICD9_codes**

Fields:
code
code_text

I'm doing a jQuery ajax call to a php function.

```
 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT code, code_text FROM codes WHERE MATCH (code,code_text) AGAINST ('" .$q. "')");
```

This works and that's fine. But My true hearts desire is to use the **Scoring Algorithm**!

Now **Correct me** if I'm wrong and I very well could be so I would be shocked if you do :)

I think it is a very expensive process to search 14000+ records. (even with a min-value of 2 characters) by using jQuery autocomplete. (and that might not sit well with some because like i said "Database aren't my area of expertise")

So Here is what I would love to know. Would it be worth someones time that knew MySQL and make a MySQL function score that would be the equivlent of

```
Select code, code_text, score("hello world","ow") from ICD9_codes
```

If you have any Pros or Cons to the Idea would love to hear? or know of a better way :)

**Pros:**

- A native way for **MySQL** to have a **search algorithm**

**Cons:**

- If I don't have control of the database I can't add a mysql function score() (which would leave me where I was before to do it in **php** or **javascript**)

At this time would slip in there (Stackoverflow is Awesome!!! amazing community!)
Thanks,
Dustin

Comment: I guess this isn't the right question.

Answer (score 1):

```
select code, code_text, match(code,code_text) against('inputstring') as score
from ICD9_codes
```

it's taken from MySQL 5.0 Reference Full-Text Search Functions section